# undefined reference class::function qt with subdirs

Tags: c++, qt, undefined-reference

I'm on Qt creator and work with subdirs and i have this error in compilation:
**undefined reference to `MainWindow::MainWindow()**
The code worked without the decomposition in subdirs, I try to execute qmake, clear ... What's wrong?

ps: I am on Windows

```
project_dir/
           subdirs.pro 
           client/
                 client.pro
                 main.cpp
           common/
                 common.pro
                 mainwindow.h
                 mainwindow.cpp
                 [otherfiles...]
          [otherdir/...]
```

subdirs.pro

```
QT       += core gui network widgets

TEMPLATE = subdirs
CONFIG += ordered
SUBDIRS = common \
          server \
          client

server.depends = common
client.depends = common
```

client.pro

```
QT       += core gui network widgets


TARGET = client
TEMPLATE = app

MOC_DIR = tmp_moc
OBJECTS_DIR = tmp_obj

SOURCES += main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += ../common
LIBS += -L../common
DEPENDPATH += ../common
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H


#include "menu.h"
#include "synchromodule.h"
#include <QObject>


class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow();
    ~MainWindow();
    void AfficherMenu();
    void AfficherJeu();

private:
    SyncModule *synchro;
};


#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "menu.h"
#include "synchromodule.h"
#include <QObject>

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    synchro = new SyncModule();
    AfficherMenu();
}

void MainWindow::AfficherMenu()
{
    Menu *menu = new Menu();
    setCentralWidget(menu);
    synchro->menu = menu;
    QString mdp_texte = menu->mdp->text();
    QString pseudo_texte = menu->pseudo->text();
    QObject::connect(menu->connection, SIGNAL(clicked()), synchro, SLOT(connectionServer())); //mdp_texte, pseudo_texte
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow(){}
```

Thank

Comment: The problem is that you compile only main.cpp - `SOURCES += main.cpp`. Add all the cpp files that needs to be compiled.

Comment: I add this in my client.pro:
SOURCES += main.cpp\
            ../common/mainwindow.cpp\
            ../common/synchromodule.cpp\
            ../common/menu.cpp\
            ../common/serversocket.cpp\

HEADERS +=  ../common/mainwindow.h\
            ../common/synchromodule.h\
            ../common/menu.h\
            ../common/serversocket.h\
It's work !
But there is no other way to do it 'automatically' with the subdir template ?